# While navigating to Register Player details screen, throws object reference error in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

On click on the `Register_OnClicked` button in the Xamarin.Forms app, system throws `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` This button will allow app to navigate to Player Register details screen from where the system save data. Could someone please advise about the cause of the error? I couldn't figure out the reason for that error yet, have restarted the app, perform the `clean build`operation, but still the same.

Database library using : sqlite-net-pcl

//MainPage.xaml.cs details

```
        public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
            {

                public MainPage()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();

                }


                public async void NavigateButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    var tabbedPage = new TabbedPage();
                    tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Home("Welcome"+' '+emailEntry.Text+' '+",have a nice day!"));
                    tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Map());
                    tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Settings());
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(tabbedPage);
                }

                public async void Register_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Register());
                }



            }
```

Register.xaml.cs details where the saving of Player details:

```
using SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using System.Linq;

namespace soccerapp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Register : ContentPage
    {
        public SQLiteConnection conn;
        public Register()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            conn = DependencyService.Get<Isqlite>().GetConnection();
            conn.CreateTable<PlayerDetails>();
        }

        public void RegisterSave_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PlayerDetails playerDetails = new PlayerDetails();
            playerDetails.FullName = fullNameEntry.Text;
            playerDetails.Mobile = mobileEntry.Text;
            playerDetails.SoccerPosition = soccerpostionEntry.Text;
            playerDetails.Email = emailRegister.Text;
            playerDetails.Password = passwordEntry.Text;
            int x = 0;
            try
            {
                x = conn.Insert(playerDetails);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            if (x == 1)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Registration", "Player Registered Successfully", "Cancel");
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayAlert("Registration Failled!!!", "Please try again", "ERROR");
            }


        }
    }
}
```

SQlite Connection class created and return connection:

```
        public class SQliteDroid : Isqlite
            {
                public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
                {
                    var dbase = "soccerpep";
                    var dbpath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
                    var path = Path.Combine(dbpath, dbase);
                    var connection = new SQLiteConnection(path);
                    return connection;

                }
            }


    [![enter image description here][1]][1]


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ8GZ.png
```

Error details from Debug > Windows > Call Stack add below;

```
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException_internal  C#
        0x1 in System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException  C#
        0x20 in Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.43 C#
        0x12 in System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw    C#
        0x6 in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0    C#
        0xC in Android.App.SyncContext. C#
        0xE in Java.Lang.Thread.RunnableImplementor.Run C#
        0xA in Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run C#
        0x11 in Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.43 C#
```

Comment: You need to look at the stack trace for the error - this will tell you where the error occurs.

If you can't see from the stack trace  what the problem is, then add the error and stack trace to your post so others can help you. Otherwise it's hard for others to 'desk check' your code to see what the problem is!

Comment: Is your mainPage a navigation page? How did u get to the main page?

Comment: Yes the MainPage is the login page from where system navigate to Register page or Home Page..

Comment: While loading the app, system displays MainPage

Comment: if your page is not contained within a NavigationPage, the Navigation property will be null

Comment: I have added the Register in the navigation as below ` public async void Register_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Register());
        }` this was working fine till sometime back, after adding the database part throws error

Comment: @JamesLavery:  Added the stack trace Debug > Windows > Call stack

Comment: Is that the entire content of the error? No stack trace or more details? One area I've seen very little error/stack information being available with exceptions is where the Constructor for a class fails when it's resolving Dependencies injected.

Comment: Is there any other way to get the full error details ?  I have copied error content from here .. Debug > Windows > Call stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug through the Constructor for your Register page, and the GetConnection method of your SqliteDroid class.

I've seen hard-to-find errors like this when the Dependency Injection fails. This could be either because of an error in GetConnection, or because SqliteDroid has not been registered in your DependencyService.

Comment: I am getting error at this point `conn = DependencyService.Get<Isqlite>().GetConnection();` in my Register.xaml.cs

Comment: So the problem is either that the DependencyService can't resolve your `Isqlite`  interface, or in `GetConnection()`. Set a breakpoint in `GetConnection` and debug.

Comment: Resolved the error after changing to `[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(SQliteDroid))]`, awesome hint regarding the trigger of error. Accepted